# DC main power fluctuation filter

Tags: power-supply, filter, emi-filtering

I want to design a filter at the input of sensor with DC power, this DC power is sourced to this sensor (analog microphone with preamp and 20-20kHz bw and it will be sampled in 12bit) and I have total 3 wire: GND, +Vcc, sensorOut. I want to ensure that the DC power is clean, then I decided to design a filter for VCC, I thought the input noise might be differential or common, then I estimated the need for capacitor, ferrite bead and common mode choke. I've used murata filter design and this achieved:

[image]

I will wound both power wire in magnetic core instead of using choke. I am in doubt, doesn this enouph? Does it required to wound also the output of sensor, It means to wound on magentic core all 3 wire before sensor? Does it required to take common mode noise in account? Also I it's better to change signal direction in picture since I think ferrite beat must be after common mode choke.

Comment: What sensor it is, is the sensor output analog or digital, does the sensor need large current surges when operating, and what device is reading the sensor output? What accuracy do you need from the system, and how clean power supply must be and how ripply it is without filter? I am asking these because unless you know that current ripple is a problem, it is useless to design any kind of filter for unknown problem and specs.

Comment: @Justme Analog microphone with preamp. I don't know what is the current ripple since it doesn't created yet, It's in design stage.

Comment: So is that for audio? What is the bandwidth required, 20 Hz to 20 kHz?

Comment: @Justme Yes yes yes

Comment: You need at least an estimation of the current and noise you'll be working with. Also that filter design is mostly for EMI purposes, in HF to UHF. Are you sending a preregulated voltage or a broader supply with an LDO on board? a regulator ripple rejection often is useful for that

Comment: you also need to have some idea of environment and what kind of noise/surges you expect.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio indeed in audio it is very commonly to locally regulate. This solves a multitude of evils.

Comment: @danmcb the other half of the evil is usually solved with differential/balanced signaling!

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio absolutely!

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio I decided to handle sensor output noise by making low transmitter imp and high reciver imp. It's easier :). the voltage is pre regulated to 5v.

Comment: @danmcb I expect no noise or spike really though the main board have operating frequency of 150MHz but I expent nothing. I want to make it just more resistant and robust, just it!

Comment: Just use a *good* antialiasing filter then, it should be enough. Also keep in mind the noise from your vref

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio But those(AA filter) are constrant in main board, not in sensor, I though maybe bad supply distortion or create some nonlinearity.